# python seaborn plot title or footnote including variable?

Tags: python, seaborn, pairplot

I'd like to be able to include a variable in either the title (subtitle) or footnote text on a seaborn pairplot -- I'm selecting for a date range and specifically want to add the dates and a name.
I can easily put a static title on the pairplot and it runs as expected.

Here's the code:

```
subData = rslt_avgData[['averageSpO2', 'averageHR', 'averageRR', 'averagePVi', 'averagePi']]
g=sns.pairplot(subData, hue = 'averageSpO2', palette= 'dark:salmon')
g.fig.suptitle("Average SpO2 compared to average of other variables, selected dates", y=1.05, fontweight='bold')
g.fig.text('Event Name: ', eventName,
           '\nStart Date: ', startDate,
          "\nEnd Date: ", endDate)
```

Here's the error:

```
----> 7 g.fig.text('Event Name: ', eventName,
      8            '\nStart Date: ', startDate,
      9           "\nEnd Date: ", endDate)

TypeError: text() takes from 4 to 5 positional arguments but 7 were given
```

If I try just using the fixed text, I get this error:

```
----> 7 g.fig.text('Event Name: \nStart Date: \nEnd Date: ')

TypeError: text() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 's'
```

If I try when specifying location (x,y), and the text (s), like this:
g.fig.text(x=0, y=-0.5, s='Event Name: ',eventName,'\nStart Date: \nEnd Date: ')
(whether I put the x and y at the beginning or the end...)

I get this error:

```
    g.fig.text(x=0, y=-0.5, s='Event Name: ',eventName,'\nStart Date: \nEnd Date: ')
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn is based on Matplotlib and you can use the syntax from [matplotlib.pyplot.text()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)

> `text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, **kwargs)`
> Add text to the Axes.
>
> Add the text s to the Axes at location x, y in data coordinates.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **x, y**: float
>
> The position to place the text. By default, this is in data coordinates. >The coordinate system can be changed using the transform parameter.
>
> **s**: str
>
> The text.
>
> **fontdictdict**, default: None
>
> A dictionary to override the default text properties. If fontdict is None, the defaults are determined by rcParams.

To use this function, you have to give always the positions `x` and `y` ans a string `s`. Keyword Arguments are optional, ant with this you can set the font style and text size.

It is not allowed to write something like `text(x=1, 2)`. All parameters, without a parameter assignment have to be at the beginning of the function call. Afterwars all arguments have to have a keayword. `text(x=1, y=2)` is valid.

In your last line the problem is this:

```
g.fig.text(x=0, y=-0.5, s='Event Name: ', eventName,'\nStart Date: \nEnd Date: ')
                                                  ^ This has to be "="
```

Because `eventName` is not a valid keyword, nothing should happen. See the linked documentation for more details.